# R ggplot2 using variable expressions in legend name

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a series of time series with ggplot2 that sometimes have greek names. As the plot uses dynamic names (i.e. the names of the variables are stored within another variable) I am having troubles to get it to work.

Here is an example:

```
# create some data
df <- data.frame(time = rep(1:10, 3), 
                 variable = rep(letters[1:3], each = 10), 
                 val = rnorm(30))

# create a variable for the group name
nam <- expression("alpha[i]")

library(ggplot2)
# plot the data as a line
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = val, color = variable)) + 
   geom_line() + 
   # Option 1: Does not work
   scale_color_discrete(name = eval(nam)) 
   # Option 2: works but has no variable input
   # scale_color_discrete(name = expression(alpha[i]))
```

Do you have any idea of how I can evaluate the variable nam to be displayed as the name of the legend as in option 2?
Thank you very much!

Comment: why don't you define `nam <- expression(alpha[i])` without quotes? Or, alternatively, `nam <- parse(text = "alpha[i]")`.

Comment: Good point! I haven't thought of that, which makes sense and resolves the issue!
The `parse(text = "alpha[i]")` is the one I was looking for! Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably this will work:

```
nam <- "alpha[i]"
...
scale_color_discrete(name = eval(parse(text= nam)))
```

Answer (score 6):

Using this code

```
# create some data
df <- data.frame(time = rep(1:10, 3), 
                 variable = rep(letters[1:3], each = 10), 
                 val = rnorm(30))

# create a variable for the group name
nam <- expression(alpha[i])

library(ggplot2)
# plot the data as a line
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = val, color = variable)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  # Option 1: Does not work
  scale_color_discrete(name = nam) 
# Option 2: works but has no variable input
#  scale_color_discrete(name = expression(alpha[i]))
```

This gives me the plot you probably wanna see. No `eval` in `name = eval(name)` and no blockquotes in the assignment `nam <- expression(alpha[i])`

[image]